# curl command into php

Tags: php, api, curl

I am able to use the api token and the command below to receive a json response that I need. The issue is when I try to transition into php.
Here is the working curl example (obviously minus the string api token).

```
curl -v -D - -H 'Authorization: Token token="[private_api_token_here]"' -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET -d ' {"status":"collected,pending","transaction_type":"sale,credit","amount_min":"50.00"}' "https://app.mobilecause.com/api/v2/reports/transactions.json?"
```

Here is my latest attempt in php.

```
    $json = '{
              "status": "collected",
              "transaction_type": "sale",
              "amount_min": "50.00"
            }';

        $assoc_array = json_decode($json);
        $urlEncodedString = http_build_query($assoc_array);
        $URL = "https://app.mobilecause.com/api/v2/reports/transactions.json?" . $urlEncodedString;
        $ch = curl_init();
        $header = array();
        $header[] = 'Content-length: 0';
        $header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
        $header[] = 'Authorization: Bearer [private_api_token_here]';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $json = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
        var_dump($json);
```

It seems to me that I am not quite getting the proper headers submitted. I kept the api token as a plain string. In previous attempts I submitted the token as base 64 encoded. In addition, I tried the below as plain string and base 64 to no avail:

```
'Authorization: Token [private_api_token_here]'
```

and

```
'Authorization: Token token=[private_api_token_here]'
```

I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: I was in a hurry, so didn't parse your entire code, but I think if you change `$assoc_array = json_decode($json)` to `$assoc_array = json_decode($json,TRUE)`, it will solve part of your problem. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.mobilecause.com/api/v2/reports/transactions.json?");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, " {\"status\":\"collected,pending\",\"transaction_type\":\"sale,credit\",\"amount_min\":\"50.00\"}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$headers = [];
$headers[] = "Authorization: Token token=\"[private_api_token_here]\"";
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);

var_dump(json_decode( $result ));
```

Comment: using CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST to GET? why? its a GET request by default.  (as for nitpicking, a http_build_query() for POSTFIELDS would be prettier, but slower)

Comment: He needs a `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to GET when he wants to do a GET with a body, as the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option will otherwise make it a POST.

Comment: Thanks - this worked like a charm. I was not aware you could use postfields with a customrequest of get.